# RegionWithin not evaluating for a pentagon

Tags: regions, regionplot

Normally `RegionWithin` returns either a `True` or `False`. Here, for a simple pentagon it does not. No idea why.

```
$Version
mypolygon = 
  Polygon[{{
    Rational[1, 4] (-1 - 3^Rational[1, 2]) + 
     Rational[1, 4] (1 + 3^Rational[1, 2]), 
     Rational[1, 4] (-3 - 3 3^Rational[1, 2]) + 
     Rational[1, 6] (6 + 5 3^Rational[1, 2])}, {
    Rational[-1, 2] 3^Rational[-1, 2] + 
     Rational[1, 4] (1 + 3^Rational[1, 2]), 
     Rational[1, 2] (-1 - 3^Rational[1, 2]) + 
     Rational[1, 6] (6 + 5 3^Rational[1, 2])}, {
    Rational[1, 4] (1 + 3^Rational[1, 2]), 
     Rational[1, 6] (-6 - 5 3^Rational[1, 2]) + 
     Rational[1, 6] (6 + 5 3^Rational[1, 2])}, {
    Rational[1, 2] 3^Rational[-1, 2] + 
     Rational[1, 4] (1 + 3^Rational[1, 2]), 
     Rational[1, 2] (-1 - 3^Rational[1, 2]) + 
     Rational[1, 6] (6 + 5 3^Rational[1, 2])}, {
    Rational[1, 2] (1 + 3^Rational[1, 2]), 
     Rational[1, 4] (-3 - 3 3^Rational[1, 2]) + 
     Rational[1, 6] (6 + 5 3^Rational[1, 2])}}, {1, 3, 5, 4, 2}]; 
line = Line[{{0.6`, 0.6`}, {0.7407477288111817`, 0.2`}}];


RegionPlot[{line, mypolygon}]

RegionWithin[mypolygon, line]
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps noteworthy: `RegionWithin[line, mypolygon]` correctly returns `False`

Comment: `RegionWithin[DiscretizeRegion@mypolygon, line]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We directly use `MeshRegion` to define such polygon that can avoid `DiscretizeRegion`.

```
pts = {{Rational[1, 4] (-1 - 3^Rational[1, 2]) + 
     Rational[1, 4] (1 + 3^Rational[1, 2]), 
    Rational[1, 4] (-3 - 3 3^Rational[1, 2]) + 
     Rational[1, 6] (6 + 5 3^Rational[1, 2])}, {Rational[-1, 2] 3^
       Rational[-1, 2] + Rational[1, 4] (1 + 3^Rational[1, 2]), 
    Rational[1, 2] (-1 - 3^Rational[1, 2]) + 
     Rational[1, 6] (6 + 5 3^Rational[1, 2])}, {Rational[1, 
      4] (1 + 3^Rational[1, 2]), 
    Rational[1, 6] (-6 - 5 3^Rational[1, 2]) + 
     Rational[1, 6] (6 + 5 3^Rational[1, 2])}, {Rational[1, 2] 3^
       Rational[-1, 2] + Rational[1, 4] (1 + 3^Rational[1, 2]), 
    Rational[1, 2] (-1 - 3^Rational[1, 2]) + 
     Rational[1, 6] (6 + 5 3^Rational[1, 2])}, {Rational[1, 
      2] (1 + 3^Rational[1, 2]), 
    Rational[1, 4] (-3 - 3 3^Rational[1, 2]) + 
     Rational[1, 6] (6 + 5 3^Rational[1, 2])}};
reg = MeshRegion[pts, Polygon[{1, 3, 5, 4, 2}]]
```

```
line = Line[{{0.6`, 0.6`}, {0.7407477288111817`, 0.2`}}];
RegionWithin[mypolygon, line]
```

> `True`.